# Как запрещать вход в программу нескольким пользователям через 1 профиль? JWT

Tags: c#, сервер, jwt

Я хочу использовать JWT токены в своей программе, для того что бы аутентифицировать пользователя при каждом разе обращение к серверу.

Но если злоумышленник узнает где хранится токен, то он спокойной может передавать его любому человеку, а тот пользоваться программой.
Если даже токен привязан компьютеру, то тоже можно спокойно обойти. Злоумышленник перепрограммирует программу и эта программа всегда будет отправлять именно его данные от ПК.
Но тогда можно по другому, злоумышленник может давать всем свои данные от профиля: Email:Password.

Из этого возникает вопрос, как запрещать вход в программу/профиль нескольким пользователям? Или это сделать не возможно?

Comment: Если вас это так сильно беспокоит, то делайте схему из 2 токенов (токер аутентификации/авторизации и токен продления), храните все выданные токены где то на сервере, токен аутентификации делайте коротким (5 минут, например), токен продления одноразовым (в БД указывайте был ли он использован), токен продления пусть аннулирует все выданные токены до него и возвращает новую пару клиенту.

Comment: `злоумышленник может давать всем свои данные от профиля: Email:Password` ограничивайте все поклбчения доверенными вам IP адресами, используйте хардварные токены (устройства такие). Но если у вас злоумышленник может зарегистрироватся, ничто не помешает ему свои данные кому угодно отправить.

Comment: Я как хочу сделать, выдавать пользователю ключ, он его активирует и получает токен, и этот токен передается каждый раз, если использует приватную функцию. Ну я думаю вы поняли. 

Вы сказали использовать 2 токена, я как понимаю второй токен будет refresh? Просто не понимаю как он сможет ограничить вход с нескольких пк. Токен аутентификации тоже хранить на сервере?

Comment: Все токены хранить на сервере. Токен аутентификации живет несколько минут. Рефреш токен, когда его применяют, отзывает все токены аутентификации и рефреш токены, выданные раньше. Таким образом, если злоумышленник перехватит токен аутентификации, он им сможет пользоваться только несколько минут. Если он перехватит рефреш токен и воспользуется им, легитимного юзера выкинет и ему придётся перезайти, что означает отзыв всех ранее выданных токенов, в том числе перехваченных

Comment: Все хорошо вас понял! Но опять же есть маленькие вопросы, как понимать хранить все токены на сервере? Я думал первый токен для аутентификации можно хранить на стороне клиента, что бы тот каждый раз при запросе к серверу проверял его и аунтифицировал. И так и не понял, когда использовать Refresh? Тогда когда время у токена аутентификации пройдет?

Comment: чтобы отзывать токены, вам надо знать, какие токены были выданы и отмечать их как не валидные. Чтобы это знать и отмечать, надо их хранить где то. Без механизма отзыва токенов их хранить не надо нигде, с маханизмом - надо.

Comment: ркфреш токен изпольуется когда надо получить новый токен авторизации и новый рефреш (так как мы хотим же, чтобы рефреш токен был одноразовый)

Comment: @tym32167 хорошо! Спасибо вам!